# My threeJS class only apply meshs settings to 1 of 2 models in my scene

Tags: three.js, webgl, gltf, 3d-model

I am creating a scene in three js with two models in .glb format; I am following a pre-recorded class and I have followed exactly all the steps. We create a class for the models in model.js and in index.js we define them.
Everything was working fine until from model.js we created a material for the models and it only loads in one of them. I have checked everything, searched for similar answers here and I can't find the error because everything seems to be fine.

This is model.js (the class)

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader'

class Model {
    constructor(obj){
        //console.log(obj)
        this.name = obj.name
        this.file = obj.file
        this.scene = obj.scene

        this.loader = new GLTFLoader()
        this.dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader()
        this.dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('./draco/')
        this.loader.setDRACOLoader(this.dracoLoader)

        this.init()
    }

    init (){
        this.loader.load(this.file, (response) => {
           console.log(response)

            this.mesh = response.scene.children[0]
            this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 'blue',
                wireframe: true
            })
            this.mesh.material = this.material
            this.scene.add(this.mesh)
        })
    }
}

export default Model
```

And this is my index.js (the scene)

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import Model from './model';

/*------------------------------
Renderer
------------------------------*/
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );


/*------------------------------
Scene & Camera
------------------------------*/
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 
  50, 
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  100
);
camera.position.z = 5;
camera.position.y = 1;


/*------------------------------
Mesh
------------------------------*/
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
  color: 0x00ff00,
} );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
//scene.add( cube );


/*------------------------------
OrbitControls
------------------------------*/
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );


/*------------------------------
Helpers
------------------------------*/
const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 10, 10 );
scene.add( gridHelper );
const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper( 5 );
scene.add( axesHelper );


/*------------------------------
Models
------------------------------*/
const laptop = new Model({
  name: 'laptop',
  file: './models/laptop.glb',
  scene: scene
})

const humano = new Model({
  name: 'humano',
  file: './models/humano.glb',
  scene: scene
})


/*------------------------------
Loop
------------------------------*/
const animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  renderer.render( scene, camera );
};
animate();


/*------------------------------
Resize
------------------------------*/
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
```

And this is how it look like: [image: The material applies to the first model, but not to the second.]

I tried to have it searched throughout the index without success.

I suspect this is the error, but the truth is that I am very novice and I have no clue how or why my children element comes out empty.
This is my teachers console
[image: This is my teacher's console (children element attention)]
And this is mine....[image: My console, my children array is empty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also a Three.js novice, but it [looks like](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/DRACOLoader) DracoLoader loads a `geometry` not a mesh so the way you're crafting your model might be causing the issue. Does instantiating a new THREE.Mesh with the downloaded geometry and material fix the issue:

```
    init (){
        this.loader.load(this.file, (response) => {
           console.log(response)

            this.geometry = response.scene.children[0];
            this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                color: 'blue',
                wireframe: true
            })
            this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );
            this.scene.add(this.mesh)
        })
    }
```

Comment: you were right teddybeard! 
At first the change to the code you proposed did not work but, you were right with the dracoloader; my model had a lot of shaders that created a group so when parsing what happened is that the geometry was nested in that group and the Dracoloader did not access it. 
I tried with another model I had and it worked fine!
Thank you very much for your help!